# Error JDBC [Syntax error in SQL statement "\000d\000a create table `employees` (\000d\000a when trying to run maven test

Tags: spring-boot, h2, junit5

I have been trying to run test cases connecting to local db for my spring boot application .
Below is my application configurations which is present in src/test/resources folder (application.properties)

```
 spring.application.name=demo
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testemployee?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
 spring.datasource.username=****
 spring.datasource.password=********
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 spring.jpa.show-sql=true
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

My Entity Model class is as follows

```
  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @Entity
  @Builder
  @Table(name="`employees`")
  public class EmployeeModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="`id`")
private long id;

@Column(name="`first_name`")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="`last_name`")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="`email`")
private String email;
  }
```

My Repository test class contains the below code

```
  @DataJpaTest
  @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
  class EmployeeRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
EmployeeRepository employeeRepo ;

@Test
@Order(1)
@Rollback(value=false)
void saveEmployeeTest() {
   EmployeeModel emp =  EmployeeModel.builder().firstName("priyanka").lastName("hj").email("priyanka.hj89@gmail.com").build();
    employeeRepo.save(emp);
    assertThat(emp.getId()).isPositive();
}
}
```

Am I missing something in configuration?

Below is the error

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
create table `employees` (
    `id` bigint not null auto_increment,
    `email` varchar(255),
    `first_name` varchar(255),
    `last_name` varchar(255),
    primary key (`id`)
) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC [Syntax error in SQL statement "\000d\000a    create table `employees` (\000d\000a        `id` bigint not null auto_increment,\000d\000a        `email` varchar(255),\000d\000a        `first_name` varchar(255),\000d\000a        `last_name` varchar(255),\000d\000a        primary key (`id`)\000d\000a    ) engine[*]=InnoDB"; expected "identifier";]
```

Tried adding these in application.properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor